# Sonata admin brainstorm

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I have 3 entities, two(with Sonata Admins) of which are referenced in the third through one-to-many relationships which also has extra fields. 1st Entity is Journalist which basically manages journalists, 2nd Entity is Event which manages events. Last admin is JournalistEvent which has Journalists who have indicated they want to cover Event and also includes extra fields like isApproved etc.

I want to create a custom list action in the Event Admin to show journalists attending that event. How do i go about it?

Do I create a custom action on Event Admin or do I create a custom query on Journalist Admin to filter journalists attending the event? I have an idea of the former but the latter seems a better way of creating the solution.

Comment: So basically you want to show your child entities in the list view?

Comment: In your admin class you can set 'parent.children' in the show function and you can pass a custom template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first list the events and then you can list the Journalists attending each event by using **sonata_type_collection** form type. If you want to filter out the event list, you may have to write a custom query for that. You can add the following function to the admin class for that.

```
public function createQuery($context = 'list')
{
    $query = parent::createQuery($context);
    $query
            ->orderBy($query->getRootAlias().".eventName", "ASC")
            ->andWhere(
                $query->expr()->orX(
                   $query->expr()->eq($query->getRootAlias().".isActive", 1),
                   $query->expr()->isNull($query->getRootAlias().".isActive")));

    return $query;
}
```

This is just a sample query. You will have to modify it.  Hope it helps.

Comment: I was thinking more along these lines where I can create an action in the event which basically gives you a list of filtered journalist with such a query. A 'parent.child' which custom template works too, just needed a quick and clean solution